# Amazon EC2 - httpd error on start port 80 - (98)Address already in use: make_sock

Tags: amazon-ec2, httpd

I'm unable to get httpd running on my AWS linux instance.

I keep getting the following error whenever I try to start the service.

```
$ service httpd start

Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I tried everything I can think of.

-checked port 80, but don't show any running processes

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep :80

(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=222 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

-checked to see if I had any other entries listening for port 80

```
$ grep -r Listen /etc/httpd
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# Listen: Allows you to ...
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# Change this to Listen ...
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:Listen 80
```

-tried uninstalling , re-installing with yum installer

I'm fairly new to Linux and setting up servers so I apologize if I'm missing something simple.  Any ideas?

Edit:
Yikes, I was running ssh on port 80.  Thanks you all

Comment: You have a running process on port 80. Please run and provide result for `netstat -anp | grep :80`

Comment: netstat does show a process running on port 80. Run with `sudo` to see which process.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know I had to run sudo to see the processes.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Thank you both. I didn't realize I had a process running on the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `netstat -tulpn | grep :80` command clearly shows that you have a service already listening on port 80 :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

Identify this service by running :

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep :80
```

Then, Kill/Stop that service and restart `httpd`.